# Link to aspx page from asp.net mvc project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have asp.net mvc project with razor views and i have in the same solution another project that is rendering (aspx) pages (reports and stuff) so i don't know how to call that page or show it inside view. i have tryed with render action and link but it just can't be found.

It's just one aspx page inside other project so i have path like: /projectName/page.aspx
Any help would save my day

Answer (score 0):

If you have two web projects I suppose they have two iis mapping.
So calling from a site to another site you use href link, to render a page from another site the only thing I can think of is using [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_iframe.asp).